# Design a O(1) data structure

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, big-o, hashtable

How would I implement a data structure that supports the following in constant time. I got this question at a job interview, and the following is my solution. Please check my approach, or suggest a better alternate approach, if you have one.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Implement a container that have the following methods:
// Java:
//     public class Container<E>
//     {
//         // data memebers
//         ...
//         public Container();
//             // constructor
//             // Complexity: Constant
//
//         public int size();
//              // return the total number of elements in the container
//              // Complexity: Constant
//
//         public E get(int index);
//              // get an element from the container by its index
//              // Complexity: Constant
//
//         public void set(int index, E element);
//              // set an element in the container by its index. index >= 0 && index < size()
//              // Complexity: Constant
//
//         public void add_front (E element);
//              // add a new element to the front of the container i.e. its index is 0
//              // Complexity: Constant (amortized time)
//
//         public void remove_front ();
//              // remove the element at the front of the container
//              // Complexity: Constant
//
//         public void add_back (E element);
//              // add a new element to the back of the container i.e. its index is size()
//              // Complexity: Constant (amortized time)
//
//         public void remove_back ();
//              // remove the element at the back of the container
//              // Complexity: Constant
//     }
//
// Examples:
//   at beginning   => []

//   add_front(0)   => [0]
//   add_front(-1)  => [-1, 0]
//   add_back(1)    => [-1, 0, 1]
//   add_back(2)    => [-1, 0, 1, 2]
//   get(0)         => -1
//   get(3)         => 2
//   set(3, 8)      => [-1, 0, 1, 8]
//   remove_front() => [0, 1, 8]
//   remove_back()  => [0, 1]
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

**My approach**
Use a Hashtable for storing values.
Hashtable storage = new Hashtable<>();
Have two variable called *front* and *back*, which signify the start and end of the data structure's storage range.

1. *add_front(E element)*

> ```
> low--;
> storage.put(low, element);
> ```

2. *add_back(E element)*

> high++; storage.put(high, element);

3. *public void remove_front ();*

> low++;

4. *public void remove_back ();*

> high--;

5. *public E get(int index);*

> index = index-low; return storage.get(index);

6. *public void set(int index, E element);*

> index = index-low; storage.put(index, element);

7. *public int size();*

> return high-low+1;

Comment: If you already have a working solution, you should probably move this to [codereview.se].

Comment: Seems like more of a question for [codereview.se] rather than Stack Overflow. Note that hash tables are not really `O(1)` (although in practice they work quite well, and their *average* case is indeed `O(1)`, they are `O(n)` in the worst case).

Comment: A hash-table doesn't imply the elements are sorted in the same order they were inserted, so how do you keep `add_front` and `add_back` up to date? I think you need a hash table and a linked list, some queries/operations are handled by one of them, some by the other, and both need to be kept in synchrony each time you manipulate them (and the synchronization needs to take O(1)).

Comment: @shmosel moved this code review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/177997/design-a-o1-data-structure

Comment: @JohnColeman ave moved this to code review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/177997/design-a-o1-data-structure

Comment: @MondKin why do I need them to be sorted in the same order they were inserted. I am keeping the index as the key of the hashtable.

Comment: @spectras Nope, just didn't get enough coffee today. :-/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about improvements to working code should go to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: It you've already posted this there, your should delete the question here.

Comment: @JohnColeman Hash tables are not `O(n)` in the worst case, they are `O(log n)`.  You're assuming that when you have a list of elements in a bucket, it's implemented as a linear list, which is how it's often taught.  But that's not a requirement.  Java 8 will switch to a red-black tree implementation if the number of elements with the same hash code is >= 8, making the search time `O(log n)` in this case.

Comment: @PepperBoy If you keep the indices of the elements as keys in the hash table, deleting the element from the front of the structure will make all the other elements to be shifted, so `remove_front` is `O(n)` instead of the `O(1)` you want. I'll answer to your question in the otehr site you posted: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/177997/design-a-o1-data-structure

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to codereview.so.com, and is already there: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/177997/design-a-o1-data-structure

Comment: Your way almost works, but the O(1) *expected* time you get from a hash table is not the same as the O(1) *amoritized* time requested.  Even if it was exactly right, though, it would not be a very efficient implementation.  The thing you want is called an ArrayDeque in Java.   You may want to look at the source.

Answer (score 3):

Since the complexity of add_front() and add_back() is needed to be amortized constant, and no memory efficiency required after remove_front() and remove(back), you can use arrays! They are simpler than hash tables and there is no "with high probability" in the run-time complexity.

You can start with an array of size 3, put the first element in the middle, so you have room for one add_front and one add_back. Then when it overflows, just move the elements in the middle of an array of size 6. Generally spaking, you double the array size on every overflow.

You obviously need to keep track of the start and end position of the array, and its current capacity, by some integer variables in your data structure.

Comment: I don't think this method would work for set(index,element) method. How would you avoid shifting entire array to right from that index?

Comment: set means changing the value of existing element. I think what you have in mind that requires shifting is an insert. @ShihabShahriar